# Kill with nohup process ID

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Can I terminate a command run with `nohup` later? Or can I run the kill command with the process ID of `nohup`?

Can I get the process ID as a result of working with the nohup command? Although there is more than one nohup at the same time.

Comment: Note that there's rarely a good reason to use `nohup` (and when there _is_ a good reason, it generally involves needing to support non-bash shells). You can do everything it does, with far more control over the details, using only bash builtins (in particular, redirection and `disown -h`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `nohup`. It does exactly two things:

- Any of stdin, stdout or stderr that are attached to the TTY get redirected (to `/dev/null` in the stdin case, or to `nohup.out` in the stdout and stderr cases).
- HUP signals received by nohup are not propagated to the child.

The first is just the same as normal shell redirection (but with a hardcoded destination, which you normally don't want anyhow). The second achieves the same goal as using `disown -h` to tell the shell not to propagate a HUP to the targeted child (which is default behavior in the first place when your shell is noninteractive).

Thus, you can avoid needing `nohup` entirely, with something like:

```
yourcommand </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & yourcommand_pid=$!
disown -h "$yourcommand_pid"
```

...which lets you later run `kill "$yourcommand_pid"`.